# How to turn pickle output into an unreadable format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

When using the pickle lib with some classes that i have created, the output is fairly easily readable to the user. For example, if i have a fill called saves, and save all my class data into a .save file inside it, when opening the file with a text editor, you can vaguely see all the variables and without too much struggle, change them to a desired result.

Heres a snippet from a save file i created with pickle (it's a game):

```
S'Strength'
p4
I5
sS'Health'
p8
I100
```

In this the value of 'Health' is 100 and the 'Strength' is 5, if the user was to edit the save file (as it will save locally), they could easily change any of the variables they'd like in order to cheat the game.

Because i am creating a game where saving the game is one of the features i plan to implement this has become an issue.

I did think about using encryption but using a second external lib is a last resort as it can be quite tedious, so i was wondering if there were any other ways i could go about doing this, or if pickle comes with a built in function for this (after researching i have not seen none).

Comment: If it's single-player and they want to cheat, let them. If it's multi-player and they want to cheat, this won't stop them.

Comment: I did consider that option, but i at least want it to be a little harder, because there are niche communities that would enjoy the hunt and it can act as a deterrent as well.

Comment: As a "deterrant," there is very little point.  A persistent player can just step through your program in pdb and figure out exactly how you have obfuscated your saves.  Now, if you're *just* trying to entertain the people who would think to do this, then it's totally fine, but be clear on what you're trying to do here.

Comment: That's a good point and to be fair doing this would just add extra tasks to do and in a very large program this would just be a waste on processing power

Comment: Have it save a hash of the output somewhere else, and compare it on to loading the save -> if it is different, just say it is "corrupted"

Comment: That is a good idea, then i could withhold the possibility of actually achieving trophies/achievements if the data has been edited.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of trying to make your data *unreadable*, you could simply sign the data and then authenticate it when read.

#### Saving

Here use [`hmac`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hmac.html) to compute a hash.  We then save the hash along with the data:

```
import hmac, pickle

# pickle the data
pickled = pickle.dumps(data)
digest =  hmac.new("some-shared-key", pickled, 
                   digestmod=<my choice of hasher>
                   ).hexdigest()

# now save the hashed digest and the pickled data
with open("some-file", "wb") as f:
    # save these in some way you can distinguish them when you read them
    print(digest, file=f)
    print(pickled, file=f)
```

#### Loading

To authenticate the data we recompute the digest of the pickled data and compare it against the digest saved alongside it.

```
import hmac, pickle

with open("some-file", "rb") as f:
    digest = f.readline()
    pickled = f.read()

# confirm integrity
recomputed = hmac.new("some-shared-key", pickle, 
                       digestmod=<my choice of hasher>
                      ).hexdigest()
if not compare_digest(digest, recomputed):
    raise SomeOneIsCheatingOhNoException
```

Comment: This is something i didn't think about actually, its also a really good idea to protect save files, and possibly the best option in my scenario, thank you.

Comment: Just to be clear: this can be circumvented, it's just more challenging to do so.

Comment: I could understand that, all the user would have to do is recalculate the hash from the new data and then edit the saved hash

Comment: @Ashmoreinc Yes ... they'll need the shared key from your code though (which won't be terribly difficult to find ...)

Comment: Regardless, it makes it harder and the average user is unlikely to understand how to do so, so this is the best method in the long run.

Comment: @Ashmoreinc Realistically, python is just not well suited for code obfuscation.

you could write and compile a strong encryption module in c and then just  call that on your save file to generate/verify the digest.

That could keep even average programmers away from the saves, although the best option is to have the keys on a server and you have to validate the save server-side, but that's not practical for an offline game.

Comment: I'd love to do that through c to be honest, it would be beneficial as well, its just a shame that i have very little knowledge of c and how to use it, but for now, this is my best option

Answer (score 1):

One idea to obfuscate just a little bit is a simple hex conversion or an encoding of your choosing. For hex I'd do (+12 is random noise I guess)

```
mylist_obf = map(lambda item:int(item.encode('hex'))+12,mylist)
```

Get the original back by doing the reverse

```
my_original_list = map(lambda item: str(int(item)-12).decode('hex'),mylist_obf)
```

Mind you this is terribly insecure and will serve just to discourage players thinking it is actually encrypted.

Comment: This is a good idea, itself doesn't entirely secure the output but it does serve as an extra step to get through to "cheat" the game and if they are willing to do that, i doubt much else would stop them